# What is the rule for the extraction of roots of squares of compound quantities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I had something like the following : $a^2+2ab+b^2$ the root of which would be found to be $a+b$

Is there some sort of algorithm that is general for all squares of this sort ?

Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: I want to know how to find the roots of the sort like a^2+2ab+b^2. I want to know how we can reverse the order by some sort of algorithm. Just in the case where they are squares. Other examples : (3a-2b+c)^2 = .... Assuming we did not already know the root obviously

Comment: See the method called "complete the square".

Answer (score 1):

$$ax^2+bx+c$$
$$=a\bigg(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x\bigg)+c$$
$$=a\bigg(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\bigg)+c$$
$$=a\bigg(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\bigg)+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
$$=\color{green}{a\bigg(x+\frac{b}{2a}\bigg)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}}$$
Is this what you mean?

Comment: Completing the square appears to be what the OP wants. Then if $c-\frac{b^2}{4a}=0$ we have that $ax^2+bx+c$ can be factored into some linear expression squared (with some constant out front).

Comment: However, I believe that you meant to type $x$ inside the bracket on the final line, not $x^2$ (in the green).

Comment: @Dave Thanks, good catch!